# Window 10 - Random Log off

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo X390 Yoga. Only a few weeks old and it is logging out randomly while I work or leave it idle for 6-8 minutes.

I have adjusted power settings, resolution, ran hardware scan but have not succeeded in stopping the issue.

I have recently noticed an image appearing on the screen before the log off happens.

Can anyone identify what this is?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a power saving setting based on a proximity sensor and/or the use of your webcam to turn the screen off, or, in your case, log you off, when you're not exactly in front of your screen.

Comment: That would make sense as a red and white LED light up around the camera. Just trying to identify the setting so I can turn it off as its a rather annoying feature.

Comment: I would start by uninstalling any OEM Lenovo software.

Comment: Turns out its a software by Miramex called Privacy Alert